# Loading values into select box based on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 radio buttons. I need to load values into a select box based on the radio button selection.
These are the radio buttons

```
            <label class="label">Good/Bad</label><input
                id="publishRadio" type="radio" name="good" value="Yes"
                checked="checked" /> Good 
            <input type="radio"
                name="positive" value="No /"> Bad
```

The select box is

```
              <input id="value" type="hidden" value="" /> 
              <label class="label">Select Monitoring</label>                    
              <select id="types">
              </select>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will append an option to your select list.

```
$("input[type=radio]").click( function(){
  $('#types').append($('<option/>', { 
    value: $("#publishRadio").val(),
    text : $("#publishRadio").val() 
}));
```

});